# Better to Destroy or make inactive db entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I am currently building out a small project and have run into the question if it is better to destroy data or just make it inactive. The data is a pretty simple entry. Either you own an object or you don't. You are able to flip between ownership and non ownership of the object.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example

Comment: "Ownership"...? Anyway, if meaning *data lifetime* or *data versioning*, that's quite subjective and often has to be accounted for in the schema and usages.

Comment: An example would be like ownership of a book. Say you bought the book and marked that you owned it and it is in your collection. You then sell it and mark it that you no longer have it. Later on you decide you really enjoyed that book and want another one so you mark that you own it again. Should that entry of the original ownership be marked as inactive or deleted

Comment: *What is being modeled? What sorts of queries can be asked? How is data retention handled (does it matter)?* e.g a Library Book Checkout system where the current state and history is desired? In this case 'ownership' makes sense. However, without a well-understood **use case** this question is just smoke. It's also harder to answer because there is useful information (that may turn into different relationships) -  Does it just matter that a person *has* a book? Is it important when a book was returned? What about books that are lost or damaged? Or is the required usage not a "library" at all?

Comment: A book collection app. Where you enter your personal book collection online. The db is full of books and you mark if you own a book or not. The situation that is in question is when you remove an item from your collection but later re-add it. Should I keep the old db entry and just flip it back to active or delete it when you remove it and make a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in any application instead of destroying any object make them soft destroyed with [ActsAsParanoid](https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid) It depends on the fact that if that object have any future use or not.

Comment: The object may have a future. It won't always. Kinda like someone who buys a book for their collection and then sells it. They may eventually buy the same book for their collection or they may not

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view, you should declare a Boolean variable for it, that could variate your value as per your required option. '0' means dropped Item and '1' means Item picked. I hope it will be the answer of your question.